# Scale clip-path polygon to size of div

Tags: css, svg, polygon, clip-path

I have a div with id roof that has a dynamically set clip-path based on input by the user. For example:

```
<div class="roof" id="roof" style="clip-path: polygon(36.2101% 31.8803%, 23.0934% 38.5258%, 39.9406% 40.3219%);"></div>
```

The percentages in the polygon can be anywhere between 0 and 100 and can have any shape.
The roof element also has dynamic dimensions but is always in a 1:0.67 ratio (w:h).

Is it possible to make the clip path scale to fit the canvas based on this dynamic input?

EDIT:

The polygon is included in a container and has a set width (depending on screen size).

See this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g3nq271c/

The percentages seen on the polygon are generated by a user's drawing on a map. I would like the polygon to fill the width of its container. For responsiveness, the canvas' height is set by JS to be .67 times its width.

Comment: The shape covers the div and the shape's `%` are calculated according to the div's dimensions. If you change the div's width and height, the shape will resize.

Comment: Yes, but that div would be overflowing its parent.

Comment: Another thing is if you could resize the polygon itself, but I don't know how that might happen. Maybe if you try somehow to translate each point equally on X and on Y, but this shouldn't overflow 100%.

Comment: There is some info on the net about scaling polygons. Try. I personally would put `.roof` div into another with a bigger size and just resize `.roof`.

Comment: Could  you explain the problem a bit more - perhaps putting a working snippet into your question would help. If the div's dimensions change then the clip path's should too so I'm failig to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a jsfiddle.

Comment: I am guessing what "scale" would actually mean here, is to determine the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates that your polygon extends to, and then transform the whole thing, so that the lowest X value maps onto 0 and the highest one onto 100%, and same for the Y values.

Comment: Exactly, and maintaining the ratio.